# Excel VBA Public Dictionary object auto populating?

Tags: vba, excel

Have 2 Dictionary objects I'm using, declared Public bc I need them to persist outside each sub i use them in, but for some reason they're auto populating before I even load them up. Has anyone see this behavior?

```
Public itmsSpot As Dictionary, itmsFwd As Dictionary

Public sub runReport()
  Set itmsSpot = New Dictionary
  Set itmsFwd = New Dictionary

  GenData

End Sub

Public Sub GenData
...
```

GenData loops thru a sheet in my workbook and populates itmsSpot and/or itmsFwds depending on the data in the sheet, but for some reason it's adding values into one or both as soon as it steps into GenData before it even starts to loop thru the sheet.

I've tried `Set itmsSpot = Nothing` just before I call GenData, but it doesn't quite do the trick. Even if I wipe out the data in the sheet, it seems to autopopulate from the last time I ran it. Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: *"Autopopulating" when?*  What if you close all instances of Excel, and re-open this workbook, is the dictionary already populated in this case?

Comment: The method is itmsSpot.RemoveAll. You might also set the comparemethod which can only be performed on an empty dictionary.

Comment: Are you using the Watch window to view the dictionaries or their keys?

Comment: Thanks, the Watch window is where I'm seeing them populate out of the blue. It seems to clear out when I kill the ss and re-open. I'll try the removeall and comparemethod.

Answer (score 2):

If you have instantiated and populated the public dictionary, there is no need to instantiate a second time for a second run. Setting the dict to a new dict is not the correct method of clearing the keys and items. Use .RemoveAll instead.

```
Public itmsSpot As Dictionary, itmsFwd As Dictionary

Public sub runReport()
    if itmsSpot is nothing then Set itmsSpot = New Dictionary
    if itmsFwd is nothing then Set itmsFwd = New Dictionary

    itmsSpot.removeall
    itmsFwd.removeall

    'set comparemode on empty dict if binary compare (default) is not desired
    itmsSpot.comparemode = vbtextcompare
    itmsFwd.comparemode = vbtextcompare

    GenData

End Sub

Public Sub GenData
...
```